# LINQ statement with 2 inner joins

Tags: c#, linq

<sub>Actually I think I might have fixed it, gonna do some testing, I wll post my solution if it works.</sub>

I am migrating an older DB system over to LINQ, I'm having trouble converting a few of the SQL statements though:

```
SELECT * FROM cities 
INNER JOIN deals ON cities.cityId = deals.CityID 
INNER JOIN countries ON cities.countryID = countries.CountryId 
WHERE deals.endDate >= (someDate) 
   AND countries.CountryId = (1) 
   AND deals.soldout = (false)
```

I've done some research, but I can't get it to work. Here is the LINQ statement I came up with:

```
var deals = from d in db.deals
                     join city in db.cities on d.CityID equals city.cityId
                     join country in db.countries on city.countryID equals country.CountryId
                     where d.endDate > DateTime.Today && country.CountryId == 1 && d.soldOut == false
                     select d;
```

Is there some particular way to use 2 joins in LINQ?

<sub>Sorry, I had a formatting error: the statement is meant to select all the deals that have a city who's countryID = 1</sub>

Comment: What part is not working is it not returning the correct results or are you getting an error?

Comment: You're missing a space between && and d.CityID in your where clause.

Comment: In the Linq statement, you've introduced a semantical difference with `&& d.CityID == 1  ` that is not in the original. Is that intentional?

Comment: Without some more information on what isn't working, it's hard to say, but it looks like you're selecting columns from cities in the SQL and from deals in the second example. That's one kind of "not working".

Comment: It's hard to tell what's being asked here. Can you explain what the problem is? Is the output not what you expected? Is there an example of your problem you can show?

Comment: The output is meant to be all the deals that have a city thats countryID = 1, but its returning deals that are in different coutries

Comment: Actually I think I might have fixed it, gona do some testing, i'll post my solution If it works

Comment: @Scott I bet your fix may be the answer I just posted...:)

Comment: Yeah @Laurence, It was, I actually feel like a fool, I've been converting over these sql statements and didn't even think to look at them to see could they be improved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the 2nd join if you have a country code for the city...

```
var deals = from d in db.deals
                 join city in db.cities on d.CityID equals city.cityId
                 where d.endDate > DateTime.Today &&
                 city.CountryId == 1 && d.soldOut == false
                 select d;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want columns from all tables involved, you can use an anonymous type for that.

```
select new {d, city, country}
```

Comment: not positive but thats not the actual problem he is describing in the question. He is talking about getting extra results he doesnt want not getting the incorrect columns.